# Remove object from list that matched a specified criteria

Tags: java, list

I have a `List` of `Pojo` which has about 10000 objects.

I need to remove an object from this `List` where `pojo.getAccountId() = provided String`.

Is this possible to remove this object without having to iterate over the whole list?
I have to do a lot of removals and so I don't want to iterate over the list.

Currently I am planning to create a `hashmap<>` from my list where `key = pojo.getAccountId()`. Using map i can do `map.remove(key)`.

I would like to avoid this conversion process if possible at all.

Comment: Does each Pojo have an unique account id?

Comment: Yes. Account Id is a unique value.

Comment: Whatever method doing the removal for you will have to iterate over the list. There is no alternative if a list is used.

Comment: Considering list, it is not possible without iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use the CollectionUtils from the apache commons library. It has a filter method to which you need to pass a predicate.

```
public void filterList(List<MyObject> myList, String testString) {
    CollectionUtils.filter(myList, new Predicate<MyObject>() {
        @Override
        public boolean evaluate(MyObject myObject) {
            return myObject.getAccountId().equals(testString);
        }
    });
}
```

This removes from the list all the objects that **do not** match the condition described in the Predicate. If you want to do the opposite, you can change the condition, or you can use the *filterInverse* method.
Nevertheless, of course, it implicitly uses a for loop, but it is hidden to you.

Apache commons : http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/

CollectionUtils : http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html

Hope it was helpfull.

**EDIT**

As also said by Narmer, if you use JDK 1.8, it is even easier. You can create a stream on your list and call the filter Method in the same way.

```
myList.stream()
    .filter(myObject -> myObject.getAccountId().equals(testString))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: Thanks for CollectionUtils. I can use this lib for my requirement. Will need to see the complexity and time constraints.

Your code works with a small change.

return myObject.getAccountId().equals(testString);

Comment: Yep, sorry about that. I've just corrected it. I personally often use the apache commons IO, Collections and Lang packages. So usefull !

Answer (score 6):

Whichever method you use will always iterate through the list to remove your element. The only thing you can do is shorten and prettify your code as much as possible.

Here is a [Java 8 one liner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
 boolean removed = myList.removeIf(pojo -> pojo.getAccountId().equals(provided));
```

Comment: @JBNizet yep. It can be whatever [predicate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) you want. Modifying answer for the OP.

Comment: That's what I thought too. I cannot use Java 8 lamda could have saved me there. I guess i need to compare the perdicate vs conversion to hashmap approach and figure out which one is better for me.

Answer (score 2):

Don't store the data in a List, store in a `java.util.Map` instead (keyed by id). The `remove()` will be a hash lookup.

If you want to maintain order, use `LinkedHashMap` or `TreeMap`.

Comment: i cant do that. The data is coming from an API so i have to get it in list. I am currently thinking of manually converting that list to a hashmap which is an additional overhead. Hence the question to see if it can be done any quicker.

Comment: I guess it depends on how many times you are performing a delete operation. If only one delete operation (could be deleting multiple objects at once) then don't use a map (just traverse). If doing more than one delete operation (over time), take the up front performance hit and store it in a map so that subsequent operations are fast.

Comment: Yes, I have to do multiple removals over time. Hence HashMap seems like a better deal.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless your `List` implementation is exotic `List` that knows more about its elements than any of the core library collection types.

Stock `List`s only ever call their contents `equals` method when checking for containment or equality of two lists, `hashCode` when generating a `hashCode` for the list as a whole, and possibly their serialization hooks when the list is serialized.

---

> Currently I am planning to create a `HashMap<>` from my list where key = pojo.getAccountId()

This sounds like a fine option.  You might want to use a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) though to preserve the iteration ordering from the original list.

Comment: Yes I meant use some external library maybe to remove from List. I am aware that the native List doesnt contain and removalByCriteria kind of method.

I am not worred about the order at this point so hashmap seems like the best option right now.